# Seting up vnc on mac through RPI ssh

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, vnc, remote

I'm currently away from home, and I would like to access my iMac which is turned on in my place. I set up the mac screen sharing before I leave, but something went wrong, and I can't access it from my MacBook. 
My home network is accessible via ssh on a Raspberry Pi. I would like to know, if there is any way to access my iMac and set up a ftp or vnc server on this one via the RPI. 
For example, is there any linux software that could allow me to acces another client on the same network via VNC. If it's possible, then I could try to access the RPI from my current place.

EDIT: After @baf comment, here are all my open ports on the iMac:

```
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
3/tcp     filtered compressnet
22/tcp    open     ssh
88/tcp    open     kerberos-sec
222/tcp   filtered rsh-spx
513/tcp   filtered login
898/tcp   filtered sun-manageconsole
1055/tcp  filtered ansyslmd
1083/tcp  filtered ansoft-lm-1
1455/tcp  filtered esl-lm
2725/tcp  filtered msolap-ptp2
3370/tcp  filtered satvid-datalnk
3801/tcp  filtered ibm-mgr
5900/tcp  open     vnc
8873/tcp  filtered dxspider
9001/tcp  filtered tor-orport
9110/tcp  filtered unknown
10628/tcp filtered unknown
13782/tcp filtered netbackup
20221/tcp filtered unknown
31038/tcp filtered unknown
32772/tcp filtered sometimes-rpc7
32776/tcp filtered sometimes-rpc15
40911/tcp filtered unknown
44176/tcp filtered unknown
```

EDIT: After baf answer, I update what I currently did:
I execute that command: `ssh -L 5999:192.168.1.10:5900 pi_host_over_internet`  So if I understand correctly the VNC port from my iMac is accessible throught the port 5999 from my Pi. Now to connect to it from my current location, I need to connect with a VNC client to 'pi_host_over_internet:5999'. I try this, but obviously, it doesn't work because the port 5999 isn't forwarded to the Pi on his router.

EDIT: Clarifying my setup:

What I have right now, where I am (UK):

```
MacBook connected to a public WiFi
```

What I have in my home (France):

```
Imac, local ip:`192.169.1.10`, port 5900 listenin to VNC, port 22 listening to SSH
RPI, local ip:`192.168.1.12`, port 22 listening to SSH
router accessible at `mydomain.com`, port 22 forwarded to RPI@`192,168.1.12:22`
```

EDIT: Here is what I get after @baf answer:

[image]
I would take any suggestion, so feel free to propose anything.

Comment: Scan your iMac from Pi with nmap to see if there are any ports open. If any service is accessible from Pi you should be able to port forward it through ssh to outer world.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the VNC port is open on the iMac (as updates in the question), but I have no idea how I can VNC it throught my PI from here. Any help or suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

On you local machine (outside your network) you should run ssh client with following parameters:

```
ssh -L 5999:imac_host:5900 pi_host
```

I chose 5999 for local port but it could be any port. You only have to make sure it is not used by any local service. Substitute `imac_host` and `pi_host` with ip addresses.

When you successfully connect with given command, `vnc` port 5900 from `imac_host` will be forwarded to your local machine port 5999.

Next you need to configure your vnc client on your local machine to connect to `localhost` at port `5999` (connect to itself at given port).

**How it works**

`VNC` server on you iMac is listening on port `5900` for incoming connections. `VNC` clients may connect to this port from other machines in your local network. As you don't have direct access to port `5900` on your iMac, you are using `ssh` to tunnel the connection from your computer over Internet through the router to iMac in your local network.

`ssh` opens port `5999` (could be any other port) on your current machine and listens on this port for connections. When you connect to this port `ssh` tunnels the connection (through ssh port `22`) to your router and from the router establishes connection to iMac on port `5900`. It is called port forwarding.

---

Your iMac also has ssh enabled. If you don't need vnc, but only want to copy a file, it should be possible to use scp. To make it simple you could try without any port forwarding. Just copy file from `imac_host` to `pi_host`. From Pi console run:

```
scp username@imac_host:path_to_file destination_file`
```

This will copy `path_to_file` file to `destination_file` in your current folder on Pi. Then you can repeat this step and copy file from Pi to your local machine.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried it, but as I thought, it didn't work, certainly because the port 5999 isn't forwarded to the PI on his router. I update my question to give more details, if you have any other idea. Thanks

Comment: Port 5999 will be created on your local machine, not on Pi. You have to connect VNC to localhost (your current location), not Pi.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, it seems to work, but I'm asked for a password, my PI and iMac password are the same, but when I type it, it's failed. Have you any idea ? Is that the correct password I have to provide ?   And I don't really understand how does it works, could you explain me a little bit please ? That would be awesome :)

Comment: I updated my answer with short explanation. Regarding the password it depends on your setup. If you didn't establish special password for vnc server, you should be able to connect with your iMac admin credentials. It should also be possible to login to your iMac with ssh and set vnc password from command line. But I suggest you ask new question about this.

Comment: Ok, now you explained me how it should works, I understand why it doesn't. When I connect to SSH over internet, I can only do it on RPI, and then from this ssh connection I can open another to my iMac with its network adress:`192.168.1.10`.

Comment: I update my question once again to clarifyed my set-up

Comment: Sorry, can't explain it better :) But generally what I wrote should work for your setup.

Comment: Ok, anyway thanks for your precious help. But I just want to know if you have understand my set-up well referring to my last question update ? And if your answer looks good regarding to this set-up ? Because I don't know if you're aware that I can't access the iMac directly over internet. Maybe I didn't express myself well as I'm from France, sorry if that's the case.

Comment: I understand you can't reach iMac directly. That's what port forwarding is for. `ssh` will connect to Pi and from Pi it will reach iMac port 5900. That's why we include iMac's address in `-L 5999:192.168.1.10:5900`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find out why it's not working. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Good luck! One thing is sure. Having `ssh` access to Pi and `vnc` on iMac the connection should work. If my method fails there may be others. Keep trying!

Comment: Hi @baf, sorry for uping the post again, but after some other tries, I still can't figure out how it doesn't work. But in my vnc client, as shown in the screenshot add to my last question update, I have a SSH tuneling option set to off, and I wonder if it wouldn't be easier to use it (if it's possible) but I have no clue how it could works. So if you could help me again, that would be awesome :)